# What is the difference between android.R.attr.progressBarStyleInverse and progressBarStyle

Tags: android

I tried out both styles and the output was the same (normal spinning progressbar). According to developer.android.com

> The "inverse" styles provide an inverse color scheme for the spinner, which may be necessary if your application uses a light colored theme (a white background).

But when I tried it nothing seemed to change the styles keep giving the same output.

Comment: Did you also change the application background theme?

Comment: Tried it, same result